# cPanel Turn of Security Token PHP

Tags: php, security, cpanel, whm

I need to turn off the Security tokens for my cPanel or find a way to generate them. I'm trying to create emails & add-on domains with scripts, but when i execute them I need the security token, I found some answers on the internet, but they are outdated.

I have read up on many forums, but they mostly state that i need WHM, which I do not feel like I need, I just need to bypass this single feature to get everything working.

Example of URL, when i log into cpanel:
cpr123.hosting24.com:2083/cpsess9423638264/frontend/

I need to deactivate the "cpsess9423638264" or generate it, does anyone have any experience in doing so?

Comment: Does your host allow this type of activity against their cPanel instance?

Comment: Yes, it's jus the security token that i need to generate or to disable :)